# Chef not run if on same version

Tags: chef-infra

I have a cookbook that installs a software package from source. The version is 1.0.0, when I run chef-client the cookbook is installed over itself. I do not want this to happen. I only want this cookbook to run if the cookbook is not installed or the version has changed, for example to 1.0.1.

How can I make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how Chef works. The cookbook is always executed, if it is included in the run list.

However, this isn't a problem, as long as your cookbook is idempotent (only changes things that aren't in the desired state).

EDIT: In order to make your code idempotent, here's a small tutorial using [guards](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards):

Assuming you have the following resource, which installs the software called `xyz` to `/usr/local/xyz-1.0.0`(for version 1.0.0):

```rb
execute "compile-xyz" do
  command "./configure && make && make install"
  pwd node['xyz']['download_path']
end
```

You can prevent this from executing by adding the `not_if` argument checking for the presence of `/usr/local/xyz-1.0.0`:

```rb
execute "compile-xyz" do
  command "./configure && make && make install"
  pwd node['xyz']['download_path']
  not_if do ::File.directory?("/usr/local/xyz-#{node['xyz']['version']}/") end
end
```

Comment: I understand it will be executed this is what I need to I would like it to exit once it realises that this cookbook version is already installed.

Comment: Then write the version number to some file on disk and check during the run? But I assume you are abusing Chef. Your recipe should be build in a way that it can be run again and again.

Comment: The script is building a program from source. There is a debian package for this but it installs the package to a place that is not suitable. I need it to install to a specific location as I have other components that rely on it. So at present I've forced to build from source.

Comment: No reason to prevent multiple compilations to happen. You just have to [guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards) the resource that would otherwise do useless work, e.g., using a `not_if do ::File.exists?("/usr/local/#{node['foosoftware']['version']}") end`. Then you get idempotency.

Comment: Lots of cookbooks build and install software from source using chef, you should look at the pattern that they use.  None of them need run-once cookbooks to get the job done.